# how to connect Docker containers without a bridge?

Tags: networking, docker, virtualization, bridge

I'm having some experiments to do with Docker container technology.

I need for a specific reason to connect two veth container interfaces together without using a bridge, Docker creates a bridge by default, so I do not want to use it.

I'm confused and want to know if it is right to do that way. Anyone can give advices and point me out some links or methods ? I will appreciate.

Thank you so much.

```
+--------------+     +--------------+
|              |     |              |
| Container X  |     | Container Y  |
|              |     |              |
+--------------+     +--------------+
       ^ veth               ^ veth    
       |                    |
       +--------------------+
```

Comment: Might help to provide a specific, concrete example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, it's possible, although you won't be able to get Docker to do it for you automatically.  Begin by creating your two containers with no networking:

```
# docker run --net=none --name container_x ...
# docker run --net=none --name container_y ...
```

Now create a `veth` pair:

```
# ip link add c_x_eth0 type veth peer name c_y_eth0
```

Assign each side of the `veth` pair to a container.  You will need to know the PID of the container to do this, which you can get with, for example:

```
docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' container_x
```

I'm going to assume you've stuck this in a shell script named `docker-pid`.  Set the name space on the first `veth` link:

```
# ip link set netns $(docker-pid container_x) dev c_x_eth0
```

And on the second:

```
# ip link set netns $(docker-pid container_y) dev c_y_eth0
```

Now you will need to configure the link inside each container.  If you haven't started your containers with `--privileged`, you will need to do this using `nsenter`:

```
# nsenter -t $(docker-pid container_x) -n ip link set c_x_eth0 up
# nsenter -t $(docker-pid container_y) -n ip link set c_y_eth0 up
```

And then assign them ip addresses:

```
# nsenter -t $(docker-pid container_x) -n ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev c_x_eth0
# nsenter -t $(docker-pid container_y) -n ip addr add 10.10.10.2/24 dev c_y_eth0
```

And you should be all set.

**Update**

If `nsenter` is unavailable...

The easiest solution really is just to install `nsenter` on your system; if you are able to create new `veth` interfaces and start Docker containers you should have all the privileges you need.

You could accomplish the above without `nsenter` if you run your containers in privileged mode (`docker run --privileged...`).  This will allow your containers to do things -- such as run network configuration commands -- that are normally prohibited.  In this case, you would just run the `ip link` and `ip addr` commands in the container, either from a shell you started with `docker run` or using something like `docker exec`.  You should be aware that running a container in privileged mode removes many of the restrictions normally placed on containers, and so it is not something you want to do if anyone else has access to those containers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @larsks. I really appreciate. I will try and come back with result.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please check the checkmark to the left of this answer.  That is both a way of saying "thanks" and also a way of letting people know that the question has been answered.

Comment: what do you mean by docker-pid container_x ? Do you mean the process ID of container_x ?

Comment: Yes, and also that is the shell script that we created earlier on in the answer.  I typoed the name the first time I wrote it; I apologize if that was confusing.

Comment: When I executed docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' container_x I got PID =0, and when I executed ip link set netns 0 dev container_x_eth0 I got this error : RTNETLINK answers : No such process. What is strange is that the two containers created have the same process id i.e 0.

Comment: Hopefully it's obvious that `0` is not a valid PID.  Is the container actually running?  That is, does it show up in the output of  `docker ps`?

Comment: I checked with docker ps and the containers are not running

Comment: It is okay now with docker run -itd --net=none --name container_x my_image. I forgot to add -itd.

Comment: But still there is an issue. I tried to install nsenter but it was not possible. Is there another way to do what you did with another command ?

Comment: I did it finally. Thank you so much again :-). I used netns instead of nsenter, the link is : (https://docs.docker.com/v1.3/articles/networking/)